# hasClass() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Just wondering why it doesn't alert ?

I am sure my variables are right and exist in this context too.

```
if ($(".side-nav .nav").hasClass("features").toString()) {
    alert('test');
}
```

To test it I have tried to add the ! in front and a class that doesn't exist :

```
if (!$(".side-nav .nav").hasClass("whatever").toString()) {
    alert('test');
}
```

and it works.

Comment: true.toString() is `"true"` and false.toString() is `"false"`. Both `"true"` and `"false"` (non-empty strings) are truth-y values in JavaScript.

Comment: Hmmm you're saying that the first example does not alert? That's odd because like @user2864740 said the return value should have been converted to a string, which is truth-y.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

remove `toString()`

```
 if ($(".side-nav .nav").hasClass("features")) {
        alert('test');
    }
```

It's like you are converting a boolean to a string?